# SP2013 Site theme "Office" not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, theme

When I navigate to

> Site Setting -> Change the look-> Select the theme "Office"--> Try it out

The *top bar color* display as **BLACK** color. On clicking "Yes keep it", the site top bar become black color the same as preview.

However, other themes work fine.

If I choose other theme like orange, and change the color combination selection to white-gray 80% - dark-blue, same problem happen.

Any solution on this issue?

Comment: can you share the screenshot, what its look like?

Answer (score -1):

Please see the screenshots below

[image]

[image]